# Linear relationship seems to depends from one value: would bootstraping help?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, bootstrap, jackknife

Statistics beginner here so please don't shoot if the terminology isn't 100% neat.

In a sample of 45 individuals, I am looking at a relationship between two parameters (Annual_SOM_rate and Share_temp_past). When I calculate the p-value of the slope (linear regression), the result is significant:
[image]

However, the significance disappears when I omit the value in the top right corner (green circle). Although a little bit "alone", this value makes total sense from a practical point of view (we cannot discard it as an error). If I extend this argument, would removing other value also impact the relationship?

My question: which statistical operation would help me conclude if the relationship that I observe here is truly significant or not?

Would boostraping help me ?

Comment: You may be interested in the "fragility index", which measures how many values must change to reverse significance.

Comment: @Ben thanks for your message. I have looked into your idea but this index seems to be for clinical trials where the outcome is binary (e.g. survival/death). In my case, I do not see how this could be applicable?

Comment: The fragility index quantifies the sensitivity of an estimator to changes in e.g. outcome values and has been generalized beyond clinical trials and binary outcomes. See e.g. https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.2105254118 (my paper)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off:

> If I extend this argument, would removing other value also impact the relationship?

Almost certainly yes. The regression line slope depends on *all* observations, so removing any point will change the estimate, and therefore also the $p$ value.

(It is possible, but unlikely, that there are data points with no influence on the coefficient estimate. Removing such a point will not change the parameter estimate, but will change the $p$ value slightly, since this depends on the parameter estimate and the number of observations.)

Removing a data point may or may not move your $p$ value above or below the magic threshold of $p < .05$.

> which statistical operation would help me conclude if the relationship that I observe here is truly significant or not?

Statistical significance depends on the observed data (and a correctly specified model). There is no "true" significance. Either the null hypothesis holds (e.g., there is no relationship), or it does not (e.g., there *is* a relationship) - and many statisticians will say that the null hypothesis *never* holds in the first place. All we can say given data (and a model) is whether the data are consistent with a null hypothesis or not.

Thus, if you have no reason to suspect a data error, you should take your $p$ value as it is. It would be good to be cautious about any conclusions you draw and note explicitly that significance depends on a single data point. Also, note that the difference between the slopes you estimate with and without this one data point will probably in itself not be significant ([Gelman & Stern, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313006X152649)).

> Would boostraping help me ?

Bootstrapping is just another way of looking at given data. It will give slightly different results. You may get $p<.05$ with the full dataset with a bootstrap - or not, and the same if you omit this observation. (And as above, a bootstrapped and a parametric parameter estimate may not be significantly different.) If all you are interested in is significance, then I would not worry overly about differences between a parametric and a bootstrap analysis.

Edge cases like these are one main reason to be careful not to over-interpret statistical significance. If you want more precision in your estimates, there is no way around collecting (a lot) more data.